# how can I use php if regex for both folders and single pages

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact|news)\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
   <a href="/">link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way I can also specify a single page such as `/index.html` in a regex specifying folders in a `php if`?

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: try `preg_match('/\/index\.html/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

Comment: I meant in the same regex as the folders, all in the same condition.

Answer (score 1):

Written like this:

```
<?php 
if (preg_match('/\/(contact\/|news\/|index\.html)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])): 
?>
```

You can define as many pages as you like (note the last `/` has been moved). Though, that could very quickly become unwieldy.

You may also wish to consider using [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
<?php 
$startsWith = array(
    'contact/',
    'news/',
    'index.html'
);
foreach($startsWith as &$string) {
    $string = preg_quote($string);
}
if (preg_match('/\/(' . implode('|', $startsWith) . ')/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])): ?>
```

Which, especially if unfamiliar with regex syntax, would make managing things a little easier.

Comment: Tried using your first option, but it seemed to only recognize the /contact/ and /news/ part, not the single pages.

Comment: what exactly is "single pages" please be specific. In the question you ask for _one_ page - `index.html`, are you expecting it to match any html page in the root (that's not what you asked for, that's not what has been answered).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the root of the website, `example.com/index.html`, and wildcard for any page in `/contact/` and `/news/`

Comment: probably `/index.html` isn't the url - approximately 8 seconds debugging should confirm that :). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :

```
<?php if (preg_match('/\/(contact|news)\/index\.html/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>
   <a href="/">link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment below this is the code that should work :

```
<?php
// you can add .* after index\.html you want to match index.html with get variables
echo preg_match('/\/(index\.html.*|contact\/.*|news\/.*)/','/index.html');
// or just make it strict to match only index.html
echo preg_match('/\/(index\.html|contact\/.*|news\/.*)/','/index.html');
echo '<br>';
echo preg_match('/\/(index\.html|contact\/.*|news\/.*)/','/contact/blablabla');
echo '<br>';
echo preg_match('/\/(index\.html|contact\/.*|news\/.*)/','/news/blablabla');

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. It didn't return any errors, but it didn't load the content in the condition.

Comment: it should match : `/contact/index.html` or `/news/index.html` check it here : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5wf-8up

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I was unclear. I meant any page inside of /contact/ or /news/, and the /index.html page at the root of the website. Like `example.com/news/*`, `example.com/contact/*`, `example.com/`